# How to calculate the number of layer for Googlenet

Tags: conv-neural-network

I know I am asking a silly question but I find no way to get the answer and I really wish to know it. People always said that Googlenet has 22 layers. However, no matter how I calculate, I still do not get 22 layers. How to calculate the number of layers?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think the correct way to look at this is that GoogLeNet has 22 convolutional layers. Count the number of blue columns and only count the convolutional ones and you will obtain that number. In this case, the parallel convolutions are not considered as separate layers. Maxpooling, concatenation and softmax are not really considered layers here as the don't really perform any computation (they are parameterless). The dense layers are left out, because we're only talking about the convolutional part. All that said, I agree that saying that the model has 22 convolutional layers in this case is actually confusing due to the complexity of the model.

Comment: Please add some code so other users can test what you're describing. Thanks!